# How can I set ProgressBar and other command to start simultaneously?

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I write below code in click event of one button, and want ProgressBar & `for` loops start working together simultaneously. So at first I started `timer1`

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.timer1.Start();

    if (comboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        TextBox.Clear();
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                TextBox.Text += array[i, j].ToString()+" , " ;
            }               
    }
}
```

But when I click button, first TextBox start to fill( `for` loops work), then the timer1 start to work and ProgressBar start to incrementing.

I use Visual Studio 2010, Windows Forms application and write bottom code for `timer1`:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ProgressBar.Increment(1);
}
```

Can every body tell how can I set them to start and work simultaneously?

Comment: That codes takes less than a microsecond.  There is no point in using a progress bar.

Comment: No. My array is so so long. It is array[144,144] and has 20736 items!

Comment: That code takes less than a millisecond if you use a StringBuilder.  There is no point in using a progress bar.

Comment: You're right, But in this case I don't want to use StringBuilder. However if I use that, I don't need ProgressBar.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` which runs on the UI thread and as you are blocking the UI thread it won't execute until your Button_Click method completes.

You must either update the ProgressBar from within your for loops directly (which will still block the UI thread and cause your application to be unresponsive for the duration) or to do it correctly you should create an asynchronously worker such as a `System.Threading.Task` or a `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker` and implement it in such as way as to provide progress updates to the main thread which will update the ProgressBar as needed.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is a simple tutorial on how to use a BackgroundWorker which is probably the simpler solution.

You'll notice in this tutorial a method called `bw_ProgressChanged` which updates a TextBox.  You would simply want to change this method to update your ProgressBar as well as your TextBox.

Comment: Thank you @Trevor. You mention good point, so I should use Threading

Answer (score 1):

Windows Forms uses a single threaded message loop, so until your `Button_Click` hander has returned, the handler for the timer will not be able to run. Read up on the windows message loop to understand why.

The key here is that you should never perform long-running tasks in an event handler. You may have noticed that your window hangs until your code is running.

To get this to work, you could use a `BackgroundWorker`, or start a thread yourself. Also note that if you run your long-running task on another thread, it cannot access the form directly.

Check [this old msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951089.aspx) out.